# Angular 2 - Set ToggleClass on closest element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7

I am trying to set ToggleClass

Currently, toggle class is working on a `<h1>` tag based on this script. But I am trying to toggle a class on the closest `.has-dropdown` element when `<h1>` is clicked.

Directive

```
 @HostBinding('class.has-open') isOpen = false;
 @HostBinding()
 @HostListener('click') toggleOpen($event){
   this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
 }
```

Component

```
 <div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
     <h1 DropdownDirective>Click Me </h1>
 </div>
```

If this is not possible, is there any alternate solution?

Comment: why not using angular's `[ngClass]` directive? You could do something like this:
`<h1 [ngClass]="isOpen && 'has-open'"> Click Me </h1>`

Comment: There are few dropdowns block in a page

Comment: one approach would be to use an array to check which dropdown is opened.
initialize `isOpen = [false]`. Afterwards use `(click)="toggleOpen('1')"`
afterwards inside ts file, based the value passed from html, you can check which isOpen you want to set to true

Comment: You could make 2 directives, one directive would allow for the toggling of a class on another element and the other directive would mark the element that has its class toggled.